# Finish The Pattern #3

Tags: calculation-puzzle, pattern

Given this pattern:

0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, $n$

Find the next item at $n$

*Pattern/sequence explanation required*

Comment: -1. These puzzles seem to be completely random and have multiple solutions. Even the "right" answer seems no more logical than a polynomial created to fit the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 12

Because...

> If you were to group all numbers in batches of 3, add them up and then get the average between them (rounding up), you get a sequence of it's own which goes 1(?) 2 3 4. Done as follows:
>  0 1 0 = ? (I'm assuming 1)
>  2 2 2 = 6 / 3 = 2
>  3 4 5 = 12 / 3 = 4
>  6 6 12 = 24 / 3 = 8

I'm probably horrible mistaken, but I thought I'd give it a shot.

Comment: Correct! And `(0 + 1 + 0) / 3)` should be rounded to 1 (as you said). It should be noted that it was the ceiling average (all decimals round up).

Comment: @ZachGates No way... I'm kind of amazed actually. I'm bad at puzzles haha. The reason I put one to begin with was if the averages would be a sequence, 0, 2, 4, 8 wouldn't make any sense. Which is why I assumed 1.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like there may be multiple solutions to this puzzle, but I'll propose one I found.

The next number is:

> 6

Because

> Each group of three adds up to a multiple of 6, alternating between consecutive integers and the same 3 digits repeated.
>
>  - 0 + 1 + 0 = 6^0 (unsure about this)
>  2+2+2 = 1*6
>  3+4+5 = 2*6
>  ==> 6+6+***6***=3*6

Comment: Not quite, but you're onto something with the groups of 3!